# js Bubble sort not processing all elements correctly

Tags: javascript, bubble-sort

I pass in elements array [5,4,3]. The bubble sort manages to push 5 the end, this is fine, but when it loops through a third time to locate the second to last element, the loop breaks and the incorrect ordered array is returned... not sure why, cheers guys

```
this.bubbleSort = function (elements) {

        //Loop through to the second to last index. By the time we get to the last index, its already //been compared with what’s in front of it
        var hasHadChange;
        for (var x = 0; x < elements.length - 1; x++) {
            hasHadChange = false;

            //Loop through to the second to last index.
            for (var y = 0; y < elements.length - 1; y++) {

                //Check the current item(x) in the array plus the item next to current item (x+1), if its larger
                if (elements[y] > elements[y + 1]) {

                    //Acknowledge there has been a change
                    hasHadChange = true;

                    //Swap the items around
                    var temp = elements[y];
                    elements[y] = elements[y + 1];
                    elements[y + 1] = temp;
                    //This continues until the largest value has bubbled to the right
                }
            }
        }
        return elements;
    }
```

Comment: you are using same variable name (x) in both loops leading to a strange effect. change one of them. and you are not using hasHadChange   figure out its importance and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, ive separated the vars in to x & Y, but still the loop breaks, an no matter what order i push my values they get returned the same

Comment: so update the above code with the new one so we can see if you have another bug.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: listen to @vjdhama and accept his answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for that vjdhama, however the 'let' keyword shows a syntax error if i use it.. any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use separate variables in inner and outer loops. Using `y` in inner loop instead will give you the correct answer.

```
var bubbleSort = function (elements) {

    //Loop through to the second to last index. By the time we get to the last index, its already //been compared with what’s in front of it
    var hasHadChange;
    for (var x = 0; x < elements.length - 1; x++) {
        hasHadChange = false;

        //Loop through to the second to last index.
        for (y = 0; y < elements.length - 1; y++) {

            //Check the current item(x) in the array plus the item next to current item (x+1), if its larger
            if (elements[y] > elements[y + 1]) {

                //Acknowledge there has been a change
                hasHadChange = true;

                //Swap the items around
                var temp = elements[y];
                elements[y] = elements[y + 1];
                elements[y + 1] = temp;
                //This continues until the largest value has bubbled to the right
            }
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

The reason behind this is **variable hoisting**.

When a variable is declared, it breaks into two parts. One part moves to top of it's scope, other stays at it's position. For Example,

```
function foo() {
    if (false) {
        var x = 1;
    }
    var y = 1;
}
```

Will look like :

```
function foo() {
    var x = undefined;  //Declaration of x is hoisted
    var y = undefined;   //Declaration of y is hoisted
    if (false) {
        x = 1; //Assignment still occurs where we intended
    }
    y = 1; //Assignment still occurs where we intended
}
```

This is what happened in the code. Using same variable in both loops makes them overwrite each other values. Hence the result.

From [ECMAScript standard 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2) :

> A variable statement declares variables that are created as defined in 10.5. Variables are initialised to undefined when created. A variable with an Initialiser is assigned the value of its AssignmentExpression when the VariableStatement is executed, not when the variable is created.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) MDN doc for more details. Look for topic var hoisting.

**Update**

Using `let` which has block level scope, you can have variable `x` in both loops.

```
var bubbleSort = function (elements) {

    //Loop through to the second to last index. By the time we get to the last index, its already //been compared with what’s in front of it
    var hasHadChange;
    for (var x = 0; x < elements.length - 1; x++) {
        hasHadChange = false;

        //Loop through to the second to last index.
        for (let x = 0; x < elements.length - 1; x++) {

            //Check the current item(x) in the array plus the item next to current item (x+1), if its larger
            if (elements[x] > elements[x + 1]) {

                //Acknowledge there has been a change
                hasHadChange = true;

                //Swap the items around
                var temp = elements[x];
                elements[x] = elements[x + 1];
                elements[x + 1] = temp;
                //This continues until the largest value has bubbled to the right
            }
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: Although the variable is naturally hoisted, that isn't really relevant. Are you thinking of variable scope?

Comment: `Let` was added in `Javascript 1.7` and is in ES6 draft. Might not have been implemented in setting(chrome) you are working on. But I think mozilla has implemented it. I tried using it on mozilla console and it worked. I guess you shouldn't use that for now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use separate variables for the inner and the outer loop. When you exit the inner loop, `x` will be equal to the length, so the outer loop will end also.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same control variable `x` for both for-cycles, should use different like `x` and `y` for example.